What language & writing system are they using in "Rising of the Shield Hero"?
Hmmmm..... What Language & Writing System are the characters using in the anime, "Rising of the Shield Hero"?
For Example:


Is it just a made up language and writing system or are they based off of any existing language and writing system?

I just did a quick search, looks like searching for "Melromarc language" might return fan's analyses (which looks very plausible/correct), and apparently there's not only 1 writing system. I found a Reddit thread and a DeviantArt illustration that cover most of it (feel free to expand it to a proper answer).
